# Object type declaration

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Ok.. So,
When you have a hierarchy of classes such as

```
public class A {...}
```

and,

```
public class B extends A {...}
```

...When you create objects, what is the difference between:

```
A object = new A();
A object = new B();
B object = new B();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you create (`new`) an A you create an A.  When you create a B you create a B.  But B subsumes all of the function of A and can be used like an A in most situations.  If you put a reference to a B in a variable typed with "A", you cannot access the "B-ness" of the object, only the "A-ness".  You can, however , "cast" the reference back to "B" to regain access it's "B-ness":  `B refB = (B)refA;`  But the cast (the `(B)`) will fail at runtime if refA does not actually reference a B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line like

```
A var = new B();
```

is kind of a shorthand for two separate steps.

```
A var;         // (1) Make a variable of TYPE A.
var = new B(); // (2) Make an object of CLASS B, that from now on may be 
               // referred to by the variable var.
```

So a variable has a TYPE, and an object has a CLASS.  Often they match up.  The type of a variable is often actually a class, although not necessarily.  It's important to understand the difference between the type of a variable, and the class of the object that the variable refers to.

An object typically belongs to more than one class.  If class B extends class A, that means that all objects of class B are also objects of class A.  And all objects of any class at all are also objects of class `Object`.  In other words, when we say that an object is a B, that's more specific than saying it's an A.  Just like when we say that Yogi is a *bear*, that's more specific than saying Yogi is an *animal*, because all *bears* are *animals*.

So a variable of type A can indeed refer to an object of class B, if A is a class that B extends.  But if you've got a variable of type A, you can't use it to do things that are specific to objects of type B.  For example, suppose class A has a method called `display()` and class B has a method called `explain()`.  The compiler will let you call `display()` on a variable of type A, but it won't let  you call `explain()`.  If it did, it would be risking trying to call `explain()` on an object that's not actually a B, which would fail.

So whenever there are methods that class B defines, you'll need a variable of type B in order to be able to call them.  Of course, you can also use that same variable to call the methods that are defined in class A.  In a sense then, if class B extends class A, then a variable of type B is more powerful than a variable of type A - you can do more stuff with it.

So the question arises - why would I ever want to write

```
A var = new B();
```

when a variable of type B would be more powerful than `var` in this example?

The short answer is that it communicates to people looking at the code.  It says, "yes, I know this variable refers to a B, but I actually only intend to use the methods provided by class A.  This can actually be helpful to someone trying to understand your code, or to maintain it.

There are also cases where it can make a real difference to method calls involving that variable.  Suppose there's another class C, which has two methods with the same name but slightly different signatures, like this.

```
public class C {
    public void process(A arg){
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public void process(B arg){
        // Do some other stuff
    }
}
```

In this particular case, the version of `process` that gets called depends on the type of the variable, not the class of the object.  So if you write

```
C processor = new C();
A var = new B();
processor.process(var);
```

this will call the first version of `process` - the one with A in the signature.  Because of the type of the variable.  But if you write

```
C processor = new C();
B var = new B();
processor.process(var);
```

this will call the second version of `process` - the one with B in the signature.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA(){}
}
public class B extends A
{
    public void methodB(){}
}
```

I hope this can demonstrate the difference.

```
A obj = new A();

a.methodA(); //works

A obj = new B();

obj.methodA(); //works
obj.methodB(); //doesn't work
((B)obj).methodB(); //works

B obj = new B();

obj.methodA(); //works
obj.methodB(); //works
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A object = new A();
```

You are creating an `A instance` in a reference of type A. You may can access only A methods/properties and parents methods/properties.

```
A object = new B();
```

You are creating  `B instance` in a reference of type A. In this way `object` could behave in a polymorphic way, for example if you make `object.method()` and `method` is overriden in B then it will call this override method. You have to take care in not to break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html). You may can access only A methods/properties and parents methods/properties. This is the preferred way when you only need supertype contract.

```
B object = new B();
```

You are creating a `B instance` in a reference variable of type `B`. You may can access only B methods/properties and parents methods/properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
A object = new B();
```

This declares that `object` will refer to an object of class `A` or any of its subclasses (when it isn't `null`).  The compiler will treat it as an object of type `A`, so you can only access methods and fields that are declared for `A` (or one of its superclasses).  It also means that you can later assign it to any *other* object that is of class `A` or a subclass:

```
A object1 = new B();
B object2 = new B();

// reassign later
object1 = new A();  // legal
object2 = new A();  // ILLEGAL

class C extends A { ... }
object1 = new C();  // legal
object2 = new C();  // ILLEGAL
```

So the initial declaration declares `object` as having type `A`.  But its initial value is an object of type `B`, which is OK because `B` is a subclass of `A`.

That should explain the difference between your second and third examples.  The difference between the first and second is simply that (at run time) the first creates a new object of type `A` and the second creates a new object of type `B`.

Answer (score 1):

```
A object = new A();
```

`object` of type `A` (you can access fields or method  from `A`)

```
A object = new B();
```

`object` of type `A` (you cannot access fields or method from `B`, only from `A`)

```
B object = new B();
```

`object` of type `B` (you can access fields or method from `A` and `B`)

Answer (score 1):

```
A object1 = new A();
A object2 = new B();
B object3 = new B();
```

`object1` is declared as a reference to an A object. Since class B extends class A, it could be set to either or (`new A()` or `new B()` would be valid).

`object2` is declared as a reference to an A object, but is actually a B object. Say the B class has a method called `eatFood()`. If you tried to access that method with `object2.eatFood()`, the compiler would throw an error because the eatFood method is only in the B class. Even though the object is actually a B object, the compiler thinks it is an A object due to the type declaration. To access the eatFood method, you would have to typecast it: `((B)object2).eatFood()`.

`object3` is simply a reference to a B object, and in reality IS a B object. It could access A methods as well as B methods.

Comment: I believe that should be `((B)object2).eatFood()` because of the precedence of the cast operator ... I keep running into that problem myself.