# just a quick thing about polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Say for class `ClassOne` extends from `ClassTwo`, `classone` is the subclass and `ClassTwo` is the superclass. if I went to another class and typed in: `ClassTwo hello = new ClassOne();` Does this mean I can only use the methods that are in `ClassOne` which have been inherited from `ClassTwo` and not the methods that were originally in `ClassOne`? (E.g a. method called `void eat();` was in `ClassTwo` and `ClassOne` inherited it but the method `void walk();` was only in `ClassOne` and not in `ClassTwo` so by using the `hello` keyword, could I access the eat function and not the walk function?),   I don't quite understand the concept of polymorphism. Can someone explain it very simply and by giving an example? Thanks you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try to describe polymorphism as easy as you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210460/try-to-describe-polymorphism-as-easy-as-you-can)

Comment: When describing mock classes, please number/name from the most general, e.g. `B extends A`; it's fairly standard across multiple languages.  Going the other direction (`ClassOne extends ClassTwo`) doesn't make a lot of sense, as `ClassTwo` conceptually has to exist before `ClassOne` can extend it.

Comment: This question is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203322/object-type-declaration/19203926#19203926 - you might find some useful information there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is true, the system will see `classOne` as a `classTwo` in regards to available methods.
I like to think about these concept as buckets, in this case `classOne` fits into a `classTwo` bucket. If I put a `classOne` in a `classTwo` bucket i can only see the `classTwo` bucket. However I could pick out the `classOne` from the `classTwo` bucket, that is I can cast it.

This also helps in the case of upcasting and downcasting, that is casting an object to a supertype or subtype. You either put the item in a basket(upcasting) or you take it out from the basket (downcasting).

This analogy might be crap but it helps me :)

To answer your question yes, you can't make a method-call to a method that is in `classOne` if it is casted to a `classTwo`.

This is handy anf many times preferable. Think of `interfaces`, basically an interface tells your object to provide a set of methods. This way we can ensure that these methods are available to everyone calling that object, the contract the object has with it's surroundings.

Also a possible duplicate: [Try to describe polymorphism as easy as you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210460/try-to-describe-polymorphism-as-easy-as-you-can)

Answer (score 0):

The question describes, mostly clearly, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that you could also easily write up and test yourself.

The relationship of an object of a class to a method or field in that class is "has a".

The relationship of a subtype to a supertype is "is a".

In `ClassTwo hello = new ClassOne();`, the declared type of `hello` is `ClassTwo`. The righthand expression evaluates with type `ClassOne` but is then cast up to type `ClassTwo`. And ClassTwos do not have a `walk()`.

ClassTwos do have an `eat()`, and so do ClassOnes. The magic happens when you also declare `void eat()` in ClassOne (with the same method signature as its superclass). Overriding the method like this allows for different or extra behavior to happen when ClassOnes eat! ... Up to here I've dropped some terms that you can surely go on to look up for yourself. Now I'll just claim that the term 'eat' is being used polymorphically there. But that's only one small example. I can't encapsulate any concept so abstract but powerful.